# Nginx proxies to app incorrectly without path

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have an application that is running on HTTPS on port 8445 (in a docker container). I would like this app to be behind nginx proxy. I have an nginx listening on Https port 443 for example.com domain.

My application on 8445 is accessible, when I access https://example.com:8445 I see my page correctly.

I would like to configure nginx to proxy me, so that the app will be accessible when I access https://example.com/mysite url. I have nginx listening on port 443 HTTPS and the following location block:

```
    #Redirect for my site
    location /mysite/ {
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass https://example.com:8445/;
    }
```

Now, when I access https://example.com/mysite my frontend has issues loading - I see that request has been proxied by nginx (I got html for page), but when the browser wants to load css and javascript referenced by the html it tries accessing them without `mysite` path, by sending for example:
https://example.com/somestyle.css (which gives error) while I expect it should be rather https://example.com/mysite/somestyle.css (which works in browser).

How to reconfigure nginx to achieve that - is that a trick for it? Or is it a problem with the application that it should somehow know about the proxy?